# How do you randomly generate x amount of values and store them?

Tags: python, ruby, random

I found a suggestion on a Stack Overflow topic about problems beginners should do to learn a new language. A user posted a very nice list of problems from Beginner to advanced that should help you get to know a language. One of the problems is to create a phone book, with random phone numbers and random people on the phone book, and a user should be able to search a phone number and find the person, and vice-versa.

So how do you randomly generate x amount of values and store them, without a database, specifically focusing on Python and Ruby.

Comment: What do you mean by "store them" here? In memory, on disk...?

Comment: Your question is vague. Do you need help with the production of random phone numbers and plausible names?  Do you need help with the structure where to store such info?  Is the exercise explicitly requiring a certain amount of names, forcing the solution to a DBMS backend or is it purposely limited so that a few hash-like structures would do?

Comment: By Store them, I mean remember the values... I'm not sure if you would store them in an array or a list, or something completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define some more parameters before you can tackle this problem.

- Are phone numbers unique to each person?
- How will you store names?  First name and last name in different strings?  All in one string?
- Do you want to support fuzzy matching?
- do you want to offer reverse lookup functionality? (I.E. look up a person based on a phone number?)

In Python, you could do all of this with sets, lists, and/or dicts, but you might also look into the sqlite3 module.

To generate a random string of letters in Python you do:

```
import random
import string

minLength = 5 # the minimum length of the string.
maxLength = 15 # the maximum length of the string

randstring = string.join([random.choice(string.lowercase)
    for i in range(random.randrange(minlength,maxlength+1))], '')
```

To do the same with numbers, just replace random.lowercase with [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

Answer (score 0):

With Python, you can use the [random](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) module for generating random numbers. For storing phone numbers, names, contact etc, you can use a database, eg [SQLite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html)